# How do I run this code once per day in mql5?

Tags: metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

I have a cycle with Print(). This string should be printed once per day only. There is the code:

```
int Hour = 20;
int Minute = 20;

int OnInit()
{
Hour = timeTemp.hour;
Minute = timeTemp.min;

EventSetTimer(60);
}

void OnTimer()
{

MqlDateTime ActivationTime;
TimeToStruct(TimeCurrent(), ActivationTime);

if (ActivationTime.hour == hour && ActivationTime.min == minute)
{
Print("This code should be printed once per day");
}
}

void OnDeinit(const int reason)
{ 
}
```

It has 2 issues:

1) When chart gets alot of ticks, it do more then one Print().

2) When disconnect happens or just there is a end of trading session on current instrument, time in terminal freezes and this cycle run without ending untill it gets tics and time becomes unfreezed.

So how do I run this code once per day even if there is disconnect happens?

Comment: Or you can use the new bar event handler outlined in this article
https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/159
[New bar event handler](https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/159)

Answer (score 0):

there is multiple ways to do that, I prefer this one for "one time per day" means

```
string lastRunDate = null;
int Hour = 20;
int Minute = 20;

int OnInit()
{
  Hour = timeTemp.hour;
  Minute = timeTemp.min;

  EventSetTimer(60);
}

void OnTimer()
{

  MqlDateTime ActivationTime;
  TimeToStruct(TimeLocal(), ActivationTime);

  if (lastRunDate!=TimeToString(TimeCurrent(), TIME_DATE) && ActivationTime.hour == hour && ActivationTime.min == minute)
  {
    Print("This code should be printed once per day");
    // ... after your codes, `remember today` !
    lastRunDate = TimeToString(TimeCurrent(), TIME_DATE);
  }
}

void OnDeinit(const int reason) {
  EventKillTimer();
}
```

- use `TimeLocal()` . if you only know times on your server, calculate time offset on `OnInit` function between `TimeLocal` and `TimeCurrent` (if market is not closed on init time.*)
- you can use `TimeGMT()` if you can define your conditions with GMT times.
- to detect closed market, you can check last incoming tick time. for forex pairs, you receive many ticks in every minute. so, if last tick is older than one minute, market is closed. to check temporary internet disrupts, you can check last tick time with more than one minute trigger.